# I have duplicate keys in a hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I know this is impossible, but I've managed it. From a SQL query, I'm pulling 1, 2, or 3 email addresses which are linked to a device. I'm throwing them into a hashtable. From there, I loop through, check it against a second hashtable which is made up of the values in the first table. This works if there is one email address, but if there is more than one, it's not finding a match, and it is creating a new key.

```
$DeviceList = @{
    "Device1" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com";
    "Device7" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com";
    "Device8" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com";
    "Device2" = "Bob.Davis@domain.com", "Jane.Doe@domain.com";
    "Device3" = "Bob.Davis@domain.com", "Jane.Doe@domain.com";
    "Device4" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com";
    "Device5" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com";
    "Device6" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com"
}
$CompletedDevices = @{}

foreach ($Device in $DeviceList.GetEnumerator()) {
    $Devicename = ($Device.Key).ToLower()
    $OwnerEmail = ($Device.Value).ToLower()

    if ($CompletedDevices.ContainsKey($OwnerEmail)) {
        $CompletedDevices.$OwnerEmail += "$Devicename"
    } else {
        $CompletedDevices += @{$OwnerEmail = " ", $Devicename}
    }
}

$CompletedDevices
```

After the script runs, if I just run the `$CompletedDevices += @{$owneremail = " ", $Devicename}`, it DOES give me an error

> Item has already been added

but it's not finding it in the `ContainsKey()` check, and it IS adding it as a second third or fiftieth, duplicate key.

This is what the end result should be for this example:

[image]

The example above replicates the issue. I'm really hoping that I'm just overlooking something really simple.

Comment: Your approach seems unnecessarily convoluted. What is your desired result? Do you want to transform the device -> email addresses map to an email address -> devices map?

Comment: Your code does not replicate any issue.  I've run it and get not error.  The resulting hashtable is hideous but it runs.  If I were doing this, I would create a custom PSObject with properties for the device name and then notified recipients as an array object.  Then you could use the standard PowerShell cmdlets (where, select, pipelining, regex, etc.) to accomplish any filtering you need.

Comment: So `$CompletedDevices` should map the email addresses to the number of devices the address occurs in?

Comment: You don't generate duplicate keys - you're copying the value arrays inside the loop, and the hashtable will accept the resulting objects as keys not by value but by identity. `$CompletedDevices.GetEnumerator()|%{"$($_.Key): $($_.Key.GetHashCode())" }`. Change `$OwnerEmail = ($Device.Value).ToLower()` to `$OwnerEmail = "$($Device.Value)".ToLower()`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen As always, you are amazing. Can you please post that as an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***MathiasR.Jessen*** put the answer in the comments:

"You don't generate duplicate keys - you're copying the value arrays inside the loop, and the hashtable will accept the resulting objects as keys not by value but by identity.

`$CompletedDevices.GetEnumerator()|%{"$($_.Key): $($_.Key.GetHashCode())" }`

Change `$OwnerEmail = ($Device.Value).ToLower()` to `$OwnerEmail = "$($Device.Value)".ToLower()` "

Both of these solutions helped me greatly, thank you!

Comment: The key to this for me was the "hashtable will accept the resulting **objects** as keys". PS was treating my variable as a simple PSObject as I added it to a hashtable not as a string. Wrapping in `""` forced it to use string. Thanks!!